# directory search method always returns null

Tags: java

This method below always that searches through a directory for a specific file called "level.dat" returns null:

```
private static File traverse(File dir, String name) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; children != null && i < children.length; i++) {
            traverse(new File(dir, children[i]),name.trim());
        }
    }
    if (dir.isFile()) {
        if (dir.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())) {
            return dir;
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

The method is called using this:

```
File leveldat = traverse(wftemp,"level.dat");
```

wftemp is the path to the directory.

by placing several println's I found out it does actually find the file. but doesnt return it right.
printline code:

```
private static File traverse(File dir, String name) {
    System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; children != null && i < children.length; i++) {
            traverse(new File(dir, children[i]),name.trim());
        }
    }
    if (dir.isFile()) {
        if (ddir.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())) {
            System.out.println("We found a match: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
            return dir;
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

this is what the console returns with the printlines:

```
-snip-
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\DIM1\##MCEDIT.TEMP##
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\DIM1\##MCEDIT.TEMP2##
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\DIM1\playerdata
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\icon.png
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\level.dat
We found a match: C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\level.dat
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\level.dat_old
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\mcedit_waypoints.dat
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\playerdata
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\playerdata\4e879a3b-c247-4d9a-8ec8-577172a00356.dat
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\region
C:\Users\mrjvs\AppData\Roaming\the stanley parable\temp\stanleyparablemoesh\The stanley parable for moesh\region\r.-1.-1.mca
-snip-
```

I have been trying for over 1.5 hours. I just dont know anymore.

Comment: Your main problem is recursivity. What you want to return ? The path of the file ? or the directory containing it ?

Comment: I want it to return the file itself. but it is burried in some folder. so I use this to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thats not very strange actually, you're trying to do something recursive. But the recursive call to `traverse` is never used. As it is now it would only work if you call it on the path that you want to find. Try adding a return to the call to traverse, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; children != null && i < children.length; i++) {
    File result = traverse(new File(dir, children[i]),name.trim());
    if(result != null) {
       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. it reduced the files that have been searches to 5. and the files did not include the file I am searching for.

Comment: Ah, how about now, I missed to check the returned value from traverse.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static File traverse(File dir, String name) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; children != null && i < children.length; i++) {
            File tmp = traverse(new File(dir, children[i]),name.trim());
            if( tmp != null ) {
              return tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dir.isFile()) {
        if (dir.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())) {
            return dir;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In case of more than one match, this will return only the first.
Bye.